# Nesting a table negates "table-layout: fixed"

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm making a tabular layout and I really need:

- 2 columns, of variable width
- columns have the same width
- columns are no wider than necessary

I have found that "table-layout: fixed" can achieve this, if I set both columns to have "width: 50%". Here's an example:

CSS:

```
    .mytable {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      table-layout: fixed;
    }
    .fifty {
      width: 50%;
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <table class="mytable" border=1>
        <tr>
            <td class="fifty">hello</td>
            <td class="fifty">x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="fifty">a</td>
            <td class="fifty">longer</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="fifty">reallyreallylong</td>
            <td class="fifty">medium</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

This is exactly what I want, and I'm happy, **except** that everything goes out the window when this table appears within another table. In that case, all columns shrink to the minimum possible size (at least for my version of Chrome).

Here is a jsFiddle demonstrating my dilemma: http://jsfiddle.net/KTkZm/

Can anyone shed light on this, and hopefully find a way to get the inner table to render as it does outside of the table? Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. Haven't been able to make it work, but I did find that `table-layout:fixed` has no effect whatsoever. I mean, removing it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Check below `jsfiddle` link. It's Working Fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/KTkZm/14/

Comment: Many people cannot access jsfiddle.  If you can include a summary of the code (you don't need to paste everything just the important things), it will allow more people to use your answer in the future.

Comment: Only with your exact font settings. On my browsers, it's all different.

Comment: This solution is to add a "width: NNNpx" style to the outer table. While it does appear to revive the "table-layout: fixed" behavior of the inner table, it clips things and it also presupposes that I know the final width of the inner table (I don't in this case). But there does seem to be something significant about setting the width of the outer table. "width: auto" does *something* reasonable, but still makes the inner table wider than it needs to be..

Comment: @mikero, please post your comment as an answer and accept it. Came here to post the answer I found myself to see you'd already fixed it!